# Clisp error message: an object cannot start with #\). What does this mean?

Tags: common-lisp, quote, clisp

Please see this example. I am using GNU CLISP 2.49.

```
(defparameter *pudding-eater* 'henry')
;; output: 
READ from
#<INPUT CONCATENATED-STREAM #<INPUT STRING-INPUT-STREAM> #<IO TERMINAL-STREAM>>: an
  object cannot start with #\)

(defparameter *pudding-eater* 'henry)
;; output: 
*PUDDING-EATER*
```

I do understand that it is the double quotes that are causing the problem. What I do *not* understand is that, what does `an object cannot start with #\)` mean? Where did I start with `#\)`? I was expecting some error message like `umatched parenthesis`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your extra quote character after `'henry` is the start of another object, which would make sense in a context like:

```
(defparameter *pudding-eater* 'henry '(a b c))
```

(if defparameter took that many arguments, anyway)

But, the next character after your quote is a close-paren. The Common Lisp notation for displaying a character (rather than a symbol, string, etc) is a `#\` prefix, followed by the character.

So, the error message is not saying anything about the `\` or `#` characters, only `)`, and it's telling you you have one where it expected more expressions instead of the end of the current one (because you started an expression by adding that `'` character).

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers pointed out, `#\(` is the syntax to represent the `(` character. See section [2.4.8 Sharpsign](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/02_dh.htm). First the reader sees `#`, then dispatches on the next character,  `\` (backslash) which is used to read character objects. Your error message is thus saying that `)` was unexpected in your input.

#### Error message

> I was expecting some error message like umatched parenthesis.

This is basically what the error is saying, and other implementations like  SBCL produce the message you expect. I am working from Emacs:

```
CL-USER> )
```

... enters the debugger with `unmatched close parenthesis` and a backtrace.

Let's see why. Using [`GET-MACRO-CHARACTER`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set_ma.htm), we ask our Common Lisp implementation to return the function associated with the `#\)` character:

```
CL-USER> (get-macro-character #\))
SB-IMPL::READ-RIGHT-PAREN
NIL
```

In Emacs, the resulting value is a shown as a *presentation*, which allows us to inspect it. You can also point the name of the function, and if your installation of SBCL allows it (e.g. you installed from source), you can go to the definition with <kbd>M-.</kbd>:

```
(defun read-right-paren (stream ignore)
  (declare (ignore ignore))
  (simple-reader-error stream "unmatched close parenthesis"))
```

The same with CLISP produces the error you see. We can also do:

```
CL-USER> (get-macro-character #\))
#<SYSTEM-FUNCTION SYSTEM::RPAR-READER>
NIL
```

However the source definition for that system function is not so clear (if you are curious see the non-official [mirror](https://github.com/JoshCheek/clisp/tree/e65a18f16de2b35791216f93bdf3c4c2376e426d)), but it is not surprising that another error message is displayed.

#### The read-table and how Lisp reads lists of expressions

The behavior depends on which functions is bound in the current [readtable](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_aa.htm) to the character being read.
All implementations signal an error in that case, because **when you reach a point where you have to lookup into the readtable for a closing parenthesis, the input is necessarily badly formed**. It is the job of a function like [`READ-DELIMITED-LIST`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_del.htm), called from the function associated with the **opening parenthesis**, a.k.a. `#\(`,  to read until it find the corresponding closing parenthesis. *Note that if you look-up the reader for `#\(` in SBCL, it does not use `read-delimited-list`, but a different, specialized version. It is a little bit too long to post it here*.

#### Quote and recursive reading

In your case, you also have quote. How does quote behave?

```
(defun read-quote (stream ignore)
  (declare (ignore ignore))
  (list 'quote (read stream t nil t)))
```

It builds a list starting with `quote` and containing a sub-expression obtained by calling [`READ`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) recursively. This is just as above, when I entered a closing parenthesis at the REPL prompt. Since we are not currently in the context of an open parenthesis, we encounter the `#\)` character, look it up in the readtable  and signal an error.

Answer (score 2):

You write

```
'henry')
```

`'` is a *terminating macro char* in Common Lisp.

*Terminating* means:

> if it appears while parsing a token, it terminates that token.

So the second quote character terminates the token before, here `henry`.

We have: quote, henry, quote, closing parenthesis.

The quote character is a *macro character*, which specifically causes another object to be read. `'some-object` is read as `(QUOTE some-object)`. `some-object` can be any data: a number, a string, a list, a symbol, ...

Thus a new object is being read and textual representations of objects can not start with a closed parenthesis. Closed parentheses are used to end lists or cons cells.

If you wanted a closing parenthesis in a symbol, you would need to escape it:

```
CL-USER 3 > '\)
\)

CL-USER 4 > '|)|
\)

CL-USER 5 > '|)woaaah(|
|)woaaah(|
```